# differentiate left translation

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have a Lie group $\big(G,\,\circ\,\big)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ where the law $\,\circ\,$ is defined by

$$
\big(x,\,y,\,z\big)\circ\big(x',\,y',\,z'\big) = \big(x+x',\,z+z'+xy',\,y+y'\big)
$$

We denote the left-translation by $\,L_g: p \to g\circ p$.

Considering a tangent vector $\,v=\big(v_1,\,v_2,\,v_3\big)\,$ of $T_xG$,
is it easy to compute $\big(dL_g\big)_p$ ?

I mean do we have 
$$\big(dL_g\big)_p(v) = v_1\big(1,\,0,\,0\big) + v_2\big(0,\,x,\,1\big)+v_3\big(0,\,1,\,0\big) = \big(v_1,\,x\,v_2+v_3,\,v_2\big)\; ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting with a tangent vector in $T_xG$, you want to compute the Jacobian of $L_g$ at point $p$.  Remember that $T_xG$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you have any vector contained in there.  Now

$$
(dL_g)_p \;\; =\;\; \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\partial_{g_1} (g_1 + p_1) & \partial_{g_2}(g_1 + p_1) & \partial_{g_3}(g_1 + p_1) \\
\partial_{g_1}(g_3 + p_3 + g_1p_2) & \partial_{g_2}(g_3 + p_3 + g_1p_2) & \partial_{g_3}(g_3 + p_3 + g_1p_2) \\
\partial_{g_1}(g_2 + p_2) &\partial_{g_2}(g_2 + p_2) & \partial_{g_3}(g_2 + p_2)
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
p_2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Then for any vector $v = [v_1 \; v_2 \; v_3 ]^T$ we have

$$
(dL_g)_p(v) \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
v_1 \\
p_2v_1 + v_3 \\
v_2\\
\end{array}\right ].
$$